# Alias in csh with arg 1,2 can not form output string with '-' in between arg1 and arg2

Tags: linux, shell, csh

Alias with arguments say !:1 and !:2 in **csh** cannot form a output string of form abc-def, where arg1 is abc and arg2 is def. following is my alias in ~/.cshrc:

```
alias entry     echo \!:1-\!:2
```

if i say

```
>entry Name Thomson
```

the output is **NameThomson**, what I want is : **Name-Thomson**

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the dash: add another \ before the -
`alias eee 'echo \!:1\-\!:2'`
csh > eee Name Thomson
Name-Thomson